# Looping through a block of codes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

i am trying to loop through a block of codes to assign four different element to different Id's, i want to use a for loop with if/else statements but one way or the other i seem not to get my conditions right. Any suggestions on how to write the if/else statements? Thanks... Below are my codes which executes perfectly..

```
   player = temp[index];
   document.getElementById("forward-one").appendChild(player);
   temp.splice(index, 1);
   //console.log(temp);

   index = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length);
   player = temp[index];
   document.getElementById("defender-one").appendChild(player);
   temp.splice(index, 1);
   //console.log(temp);

   index = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length);
   player = temp[index];
   document.getElementById("forward-two").appendChild(player);
   temp.splice(index, 1);
   //console.log(temp);

   index = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length);
   player = temp[index];
   document.getElementById("defender-two").appendChild(player);
   temp.splice(index, 1);
   //console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all put your code into a function so youre not repeating yourself all the time.

```
function doStuff(elementId, index) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random()*temp.length);
    player = temp[index];
    document.getElementById(elementId).appendChild(player);
    temp.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Then check your conditions and call your function with the element id that is used dependent on the condition.

```
for (var i = 0; i < whatever.length; i++) {
    if(someCondition) {
        doSomething("forward-one", whatever[i]);
    } else if (someotherCondition) {
        doSomthing("defender-one", whatever[i]);
    } else {
        doSomething("defender-two", whatever[i]);
    }
};
```